# Why aren't all possible VEVs of the Higgs field in (quantum) superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, standard-model, higgs

It is is usually said the the Higgs field chooses a Vacuum Expectation Value (VEV), around which we now expand our field operators. From this a mass term emerges, and one or more gauge fields acquire mass.

Actually the Higgs VEV is one of the free parameters of the Standard Model, i.e. one that needs to measured experimentally.

**Shouldn't all possible VEVs be in quantum superposition though, until we make a measurment of it?**

Does the fact the other parts of the Standard Model Lagrangian couple to the Higgs field constitute a measurement, in the quantum sense?

Comment: Expand what the abbreviation stands for: Vacuum *expectation value*. Expectation values are well-defined even without a measurement.

Comment: I expanded it in the question...

Comment: But if they are all equally possible, isn't the expection value just 0?

Comment: No, you didn't expand in the question because you talk about a "superposition of expectation values". Such a thing does not exist. You write the Higgs potential into the Lagrangian and calculate the VEV. That's a number. What do you want to "superimpose" here?

Comment: I meant I wrote VEV out in the first line of the question.
In my mind I have the Mexican-hat potential picutre of the Higgs potential. As far as I know, every point along the circle of minima is valid choice. So you just pick one. And this is the VEV, if I understand correctly. But aren't all the others equally good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will allow me to make your question slightly more precise, I think you are asking the following:

*In spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB), generally speaking, we say that the system has a range (either continuous or discrete) of possible degenerate values, and as a result it picks at random one of these configurations, resulting in a state without the symmetry of the underlying Hamiltonian. But why should it do this? After all, generally speaking in quantum mechanics if several states are degenerate, one expects a quantum system at that energy to be in some undetermined superposition over these states.*

I agree with you that people are usually rather careless about discussing this, but the resolution is something like what you propose. Some nice thoughts on this can be found in the [blog of Gen Zhang](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028084144/http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Egz218/); I will more or less reproduce them here.

One does not necessarily need a measurement to make SSB make sense, but one does need decoherence. A superposition over the degenerate states of a system in SSB is necessarily a macroscopic superposition, and as a result we can expect that it will decohere along the relevant basis very quickly.

A useful model, as usual, is of a magnetic material. Let's imagine a [Heisenberg magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)), which is just a bunch of spins that can each rotate freely in 3D but have some nearest-neighbor dipole interactions. Below some critical temperature, the preferential state is for most of the dipoles to be aligned with each other and a net magnetization to develop. But without an external field it doesn't matter which direction they all end up pointing along.

So let's imagine starting with a bunch of these spins, and cooling them below the magnetization temperature. Also, imagine doing this in such a way that we extract heat, but no information about the overall magnetization leaves the system. Then we would indeed have to expect that the system is in some superposition over magnetized states in every direction. However, as soon as anything is coupled to the magnetization, which will almost always be very quickly for a macroscopic system, it will become entangled and decohere along the basis of different magnetizations, so any given observer will see the system as having picked, at random, one of the possible orientations.

The Higgs case specifically is a little harder to think about, and also somewhat outside my expertise, so I certainly invite any remarks from high-energy people. That said, I think it should end up similarly. The Higgs field couples to fermions with a form like:

$\lambda \bar{\psi}_L \phi \psi_R+h.c.$,

where $\psi$ are the fermionic operators of a given chirality, and $\phi=\phi_0 e^{i \theta}$ is the Higgs field at the Mexican hat minimum $\phi_0$. One normally considers a single definite value for $\phi$, in which case its phase is not observable, but if $\phi$ was in a quantum superposition like: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\phi_0(e^{i \theta_1}+e^{i \theta_2})$ one would expect this to lead to a superposition of mass states with different phases for any given fermion. Quantum fluctuations about either of $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$ would then affect the cancellation between these two phases and change the masses of everything, certainly resulting in observable consequences and entanglement with other degrees of freedom. Ultimately, only a configuration with a single $\theta$ would be stable against this decohering mechanism.

Finally, as Gen Zhang also mentions, some nice general discussion of this aspect of SSB, in the context of Bose condensation, can be found in Leggett's textbook *Quantum Liquids.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what causes decoherence in the Standard Model Lagrangian? I mean, ideally there would not be any decohering mechanisms and all phases would be in a superposition - but as you said this is not the case, so what is it that makes it so?

Comment: Hi @SuperCiocia- this is a very general question, so I recommend you read more about decoherence in general (I suggest quant-ph/0306072 to start). But briefly, decoherence is a very general phenomenon. The minimal model needed for it is simply two entangled particles. One expects fast and irreversible decoherence whenever a large number of quantum objects are able to interact, so that any given object quickly becomes entangled with many others. In this respect, a system described by the standard model is no different than any other interacting quantum system.

Comment: But which term, in the SM Lagrangian, is triggering decoherence? I mean, in QM the system is perfectly coherent until we include interactions with the environment. There should be no environment in the SM Lagrangian, since it is the most fudamental description of nature that we have? I.e. the background should be taken into account in another term in the same Lagrangian.

Comment: If one faithfully keeps track of every degree of freedom, then there is indeed no decoherence, and therefore I would expect no ssb. This would mean, for example, that a model of the whole universe that is closed and starts before the electroweak phase transition ends up in a superposition of values for the Higgs, instead of a single value.

Comment: *However*, even in such a system without decoherence, one can see its predecessor, in the following sense: the system is most easily written in a preferred basis, whose structure is determined by the way it is entangled. In other words, for such a model of the universe one would end up with a superposition of Higgs values, but any "reasonable" observable (by some set of criteria) will only have one value of the Higgs field, and thus every observer only sees one of the possible values. So for all practical purposes one can simply pick an arbitrary value along the energy minimum and use it.

Comment: This perspective should be quite reminiscent of Everettian many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, which tends to be natural (in my opinion, and others') when looking at the evolution of the universe as a whole. In that formulation, these separate realities deliniated by entanglement, each of which for example having a different value of the Higgs field, is called a branch of the universal wavefunction.